# Is it possible to use react as the front end and laravel as the backend without using the nodejs at server side

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I want to use react js with laravel. then is it mandatory to install nodejs in my  server? Because I don't want to use CDN links to use react js in my project.

Comment: React is a front-end framework-- it is completely agnostic to the backend that you are serving it from.  Was that your concern?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: yes, u can use Laravel as backed and react as a front end. u can check I had created one demo on that https://github.com/asifvora/laravel-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you'll probably want Node and Webpack in your development environment to compile react.